# Blank magento admin after uninstall extension from magento connect

Tags: extensions

I have a serious problem, after uninstall extension from magento connect i see blank magento admin, nothing is visible to find out.

I also removed files under downloader/.cache directory of magento root but nothing get fixed.
Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: can you uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in your `index.php` and also enable the `developer mode` code to see if it outputs any errors? If this is a live webshop I suggest putting an IP check around it

Comment: Have you contacted the module developer for help as well? They may know why/what. It can be caused by EAV attributes that reference a class file in that module, which now no longer exist. Check the modules install folder (setup scripts) for any attributes created and remove them from the database.

Comment: Can you follow this guide and report back your findings: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/336

Answer (score 1):

again, this is pretty easy to debug. example:
Apache server:
login to your server and:
find Apache error log location:
first get the configuration file:

```
~/#: httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)
Syntax OK
```

look for ErrorLog path:

```
~/#: grep ErrorLog /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
ErrorLog "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
```

use tail to read the latest log entries:

```
~/#: tail -f /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
```

Nginx server:

```
~/#: cd /var/log/nginx
~/#: tail -f error.log
```

Magento internal logs:
if you are not sure where is the shop installed:

```
~/#: updatedb
~/#: locate app/etc/local.xml
~/#: /var/www/html/shop.com/app/etc/local.xml
```

if you are the owner or you know where is the shop:

```
~/#: cd /var/www/html/shop.com/var/log
~/#: ls
~/#: exception.log   system.log
~/#: tail -f system.log
```

open your browser and go to your admin page (or any page that fails or blank, etc), click it few times, press F5, etc.
and see your error log fills-in with error messages.

but obviously you have to flush the cache storage and clear opcode cache as well,
dont forget about memcached and redis :)

*p.s: This example uses the default options.
Your server may use different configurations and paths.*